# Troubles getting results from ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, resultset

How can I have a var which contains all the records I get from a resultset?

So far I have this code:

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            String resultado = "";
            resultado = rs.getString(i);
            columnValue += resultado;
        }
        jTextPane2.setText(jTextPane2.getText() + columnValue + ", ");
    }
```

I want that when `resultado` gets the value from the `rs.getString(i)`, fills the var `columnValue` so that I have a var which SHOULD have all the records I get from the rs, but is not working. Any help?

The result I get is:

> (id_tlf, cod_area)
>
> 1+58, 1+582+104, 1+582+1043+60

so as you see, the first 2 results repeat in every row

Comment: Thanks to everyone, this really helped me!

Comment: ***FYI:*** Question reposted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636693/placing-a-coma-after-a-rs

Answer (score 1):

Please prefer a `StringBuilder` to creating lots of `String` temporary values (they pollute the intern cache for one thing). Next, you don't need to store each column in another local variable. Basically, I would do something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        if (i != 1) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(rs.getString(i));
    }
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
jTextPane2.setText(sb.toString());
```

**Note** the above clears `jTextPane2`, if you intend to append then you could change the first line to to something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(jTextPane2.getText());
sb.append(System.lineSeparator()); // <-- start the next line... and then iterate rs
```

Comment: `rs.getString(i)` will fail for `i = 0`. JDBC parameters are 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

You are accumulation the column value each inner iteration (without reinitializing to the empty string each outer iteration):

```
columnValue+=resultado;
```

And you are accumulation the total message each outer iteration:

```
jTextPane2.setText(jTextPane2.getText() + columnValue + ", ");
```

Pick one  :-)

---

I'd recommend using (Java 8) [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), and only updating `jTextPane2` at the end of the loop:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
while (rs.next()) {
    StringBuilder columnValue = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        columnValue.append(rs.getString(i));
    }
    sj.add(columnValue.toString());
}
jTextPane2.setText(sj.toString());
```

Comment: I'd recommend not doing `string += string` in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder()`. And remove the double-`;`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand right, but it could be something like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
         String resultado = "";
         resultado = rs.getString(i);
         columnValue+=resultado;
    }
    columnValue+=", ";
}
jTextPane2.setText(columnValue);
```

Comment: I'd recommend not doing `string += string` in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder()`.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is your columnValue and your jTextPane.

When you want to add the text to your jTextPane, you are adding the text you already have inside the textpane AND you add add the columnValue text (which is already within the textpane).

Within your for loop, you write the following to get the result:

```
columnValue+=resultado;
```

Here you should write

```
columnValue=resultado;
```

This should fix your problem.

I hope that I could help you.

Best regards. Levkaz