# Placing a comma after a RS

Tags: java, mysql

I fixed the problem I had with my rs, and now here's my code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        String resultado = "";
        resultado = rs.getString(i);
        columnValue += resultado;
    }
    columnValue += "), (";
}
String sub = columnValue.substring(0, columnValue.length() - 3);
jTextPane2.setText(jTextPane2.getText() + sub);
sub = "";
columnValue = "";
jTextField1.setText("");
```

and the Result I get is this:

(id_tlf, cod_area)

(1+58), (2+104), (3+100)

How should I edit my code so that it looks like this:

(id_tlf, cod_area)

(1, +58), (2, +104), (3, +100)

If you see, I want to add a comma after the first rs and not on the 2nd one

Comment: Show us the source data from your table.

Comment: Is a SQL manager... So I get to create every database I want and the tables I want to, thats why I need to know the answer to my question @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Go back to [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636398/troubles-getting-results-from-resultset) and read [answer by Elliott Frisch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36636493/5221149). That should guide you to where you want to be.

Comment: That really helped me out, got exactly what I wanted! @Andreas if u can check my last question and give me a proper answer I'd be very appreciate